# Android vibrator service error

Tags: android, android-vibration

Does anyone know why my vibrate service is having an error when I click the `Buttons`? It says `"....... force close"`. Here's my code:

```
final Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent newgameIntent = new Intent(BodyPartsGameActivity.this,gamelevel.class);
    startActivity(newgameIntent);
    mp.start();
    mVibrator.vibrate(500);
}
```

Comment: You are likely missing a permission for the vibrator in your manifest, but you'll also want to learn to run logcat from the command line or ddms or the lower pane in eclipse, so that you can see that developer-level error message instead of just the end user pop up dialog.

Comment: Why does this have an iPhone tag?

Comment: what does this have to do with a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the permission to use the vibrator. Otherwise the security framework will shut down your application.

```
<manifest>
    ...
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    ...
</manifest>
```